# Is there a way to iterate through all existing groups automatically?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, pygame, sprite

I guess this might be a trivial question, nonetheless I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I am currently building a small rpg style game and I am starting to have quite a few sprite groups.

I was wondering if there was a way to ask Pygame to refer to all existing groups ?

I would need this function to be able to move sprites which are deleted from my game to a deleted_sprite_group that I have.

At the moment I am adding all the groups to a list and iterating through that list but this requires some maintenance.

Note: I am not that lazy as to mind using a list but I try and optimize and clean up my code every so often. ;)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Not as far as I know. I use lists of groups myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Ni.

Sprite.kill() removes a sprite from all its groups

Answer (score 0):

Try making one group for all sprites in your game, and filling it while filling the separate groups

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am confused as to how that would be any less maintenance than a list of sprite groups ? I actually have a group with all the sprites that I use for blitting them all.

Comment: If you have one already, can't you just iterate through all the sprites in it?

Comment: Not really since the reason I want to iterate through all my sprite group is to remove a given sprite from all of them.

Comment: `Sprite.kill()` removes a sprite from all its groups